# Which kinds of post-processing effects and algorithms could be used to try to imitate images like this?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, image, lighting

I am not sure if that is the right place to ask that, I just had no better idea.
The thing is, I have a model on blender of a soccer player. And I want to create renders that imitate these images as much as possible. You can notice that these images have low resolution, different kinds of noise, some blurring, lighting effects, etc. However I am not sure how I could try to reproduce these effects in blender, or through some sort of post processing.

[image]

Comment: For ghost color ... Separate RGB node, blur and translate red channel and compose back or try Lens Distortion node ...

Comment: @vklidu good idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like digital noise and sharpening artifacts
You can use the *Blur > Catmull-Rom* filter to get a similar result

A pinch of *Directional Blur* might also help.

[image]

Comment: That looks very cool!

Answer (score 6):

As extension to @JachymMichal answer ... the ghost color can be achieve by ...

- *Separate RGB* node, *Blur* Red channel on X axis and *Combine RGB* back

[image]
[image]

- or *Lens Distortion* node Projector, Dispersion ...

[image]
[image]